# Python TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have a method which returns a list of text from a  tag from an HTML file using Beautifulsoup.
When I call the method I save the value returned from the method into a variable.
I think a string variable.
I call the method a second time and store the returned value into a different string variable.
I would like to concatenate these two strings so that I can print each one on a newline.  I can then add this to my email routine so that it prints the values into the email message.

I get the error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/test_runners/selenium_regression_test_5_1_1/ClearCore - Regression Test/Email/email_selenium_report.py", line 43, in <module>
    print rows_part1 + "/n" + rows_part2
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

My method implementation is:

```
def extract_data_from_report3(filename):
    html_report_part = open(filename,'r')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_report_part, "html.parser")
    th = soup.find_all('th')
    td = soup.find_all('td')

    headers = [header.get_text(strip=True) for header in soup.find_all("th")]
    rows = [dict(zip(headers, [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.find_all("td")]))
        for row in soup.find_all("tr")[1:-1]]
    print(rows)
    return rows
```

To call the method is as follows:

```
rows_part1 =  report.extract_data_from_report3(r"E:\test_runners\selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\TestReport\SeleniumTestReport_part1.html")
print "part1 = "
print rows_part1

rows_part2 =  report.extract_data_from_report3(r"E:\test_runners\selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\TestReport\SeleniumTestReport_part2.html")
print "part2 = "
print rows_part2

print rows_part1 + "/n" + rows_part2
```

The value in rows_part1 is:

```
 part1 = 
[{u'Success': u'219', u'Skip': u'0', u'Error': u'9', u'Fail': u'1', u'Total': u'229', u'Class': u'Regression_TestCase.RegressionProject_TestCase2.RegressionProject_TestCase2'}]
```

The value in rows_part2 is:

```
 part2 = 
[{u'Success': u'21', u'Skip': u'0', u'Error': u'10', u'Fail': u'5', u'Total': u'230', u'Class': u'Regression_TestCase.RegressionProject_TestCase2.RegressionProject_TestCase2'}]
```

I would like to print out the value of rows_part 1 and then on a newline print out the value of rows_part2.
I am concatenating it so that I can just put the one variable in the email message body which will print out the value.

Or how can I extract the contents out of the list and append it to a string variable?
I can then print out the string variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, in Python, you don't have to declare a variable type, it's assigned under the hood. That's confused you about the variable types.

> returns a list

[...]

> I think a string variable

Your print statement is attempting to print a `list` type object, then a new line, then another `list` type object. Your issue is coming from the "\n" in between.

Concatenating two strings is possible with: `str1 + str2`

Concatenating two lists is possible with: `list1.append(list2)`

But concatenating a string to a list (or a list to a string) is not! What you need to do is turn your list objects into strings (of that list).

```
print str(rows_part1) + "/n" + str(rows_part2)
```

should work.

Comment: Yes this is great I needed to turn your list objects into strings (of that list).  This works now.  Thank you.

Comment: Note that with the string versions you can't iterate on them or anything you can normally do to a list. Also, this is not an easily reversed process, list(str) will simply create a one item list with the whole string